# Bounty message for auto-selected answers - is it right?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

Re [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153600/resizing-a-charx-to-chary-at-runtime); the OP reports that they *didn't* accept the bounty. The assumption then is that it was accepted by default upon expiration; this makes sense by the numbers, as (assuming that the +50 bounty bonus still applies, making +100 the minimum bounty), the fact that 50 was awarded again indicates the half-bounty for default selections.

However; the hover shows "The question owner accepted this as the best answer...".

Is this a glitch? Should this read auto-selected? Unfortunately, it isn't clear when the bounty was placed, so I can't say definitively whether it was auto-selected; accidentally selected by the OP; or cosmic rays...

Additional (<kbd>feature-request</kbd>): please add "created bounty of `<x>` on question `<y>`" to the (♦ moderator-only) user's log...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The created bounty part is completed.

That other question has some severe fundamental problems IMO.